# What's the consensus for accessing characters in Swift string?

Tags: swift, string

A quick example would be for writing an algorithm that made sure no two consecutive characters were the same (aabbcc -> abacbc). This requires repetitive usage of individual character access. Aside from the fact that each access of character m in an n letter string takes O(n) time, the default implementation is incredibly cumbersome.

What's considered the best approach?

```
let letters = string.characters.map { $0 }
```

And accessing the array by index.

```
extension String {
    subscript(index: Int) -> Character {
        get {
            return characters[characters.index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)]
        }
        set {
            let firstIndex = characters.index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)
            let lastIndex = characters.index(firstIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            replaceSubrange(firstIndex..<lastIndex, with: String(newValue))
        }
    }
}
```

And using `string[3]`.

Or perhaps there's some built in way I don't know? I've been using the `map` since it has O(1) access time though O(n) memory usage.

Comment: I think it is best to convert the String to an array of characters, do all of your work with that array, and convert back to String when you are done.